# Removing top and bottom 5% of a distribution in R

Tags: r

I'm calculating the truncated mean of 1000 observations of the student-t distribution. I need to exclude the observations above 95% and below 5%. Could anyone suggest a way of doing this as i'm not sure at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use R, but in general terms would sort the data then take the mean of the 50-950th items.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quantile` function for this task. The solution is below:

```
#You can vary number of observation, still this solution will still work     
n <- 1000
set.seed(123)
numVec <- rnorm(n)
p95 <- quantile(numVec, 0.95)
p05 <- quantile(numVec, 0.05)
meanTrunc <- mean(numVec[which(numVec <= p95 & numVec >= p05)])
```

I used >= and <=, becasue in your question, you wrote that **"need to exclude the observations above 95% and below 5%"**.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest you can use `sort` to order your sample of `n` observations from the student t distribution and then you can select the observations of interest `[50:950]` and find the mean.

```
n <- rt(1000, 2)
mean(n)
n_order <- sort(n)
mean(n_order[50:950])
```